# MS Excel - splitting a formula into individual cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm not sure if this is possible, or if I'll have to do it manually, but I have lots of cells in the following format:

=87.12+56.52-16.50+98.21-9.51

If possible, I'd like to break it up into columns, like so:

I have a data in excel in the format:

```
87.12   |   56.52   |   -16.50   |   98.21   |   -9.51
```

I've tried text to columns based on the '+' symbol, but it falls short when I then try to break it down by the '-' symbol, it moves into columns as appropriate, it removes the minus from the start of the figure

Any suggestions would be very welcome! Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to first do a find/replace and replace `-` with`+-`.

once you have done this, Do your text to columns method you have already tried. This will split it at the `+` and maintain the negative numbers.

Comment: Fantastic and simple solution - thank you! :)

Comment: Love the logic of this solution!

Comment: Find/replace has been my friend through many a datamine.